# Kotlin annotation not in fieldDecleration or compiled java

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, annotations

For my data objects in Kotlin I have added a custom annotation for GSON to have an exclusion rule.

In the past this has worked perfectly, now it does not show up in my class reflection (`this.javaClass.declaredFields[3].annotations` is `null`) nor does it show up in the compiled java output.

I have tried different things, like upgrading my kotlin version, adding kotlin-kapt, using different `@Retention` types, restarting my computer (you never know) and have looked at other annotations. Those other annotations (for instance for Hibernate a `@OneToOne`) shows up with no issue.

**Annotation definition:**

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Repeatable
@Target(
        AnnotationTarget.FIELD,
        AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
        AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER,
        AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY,
        AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER
)
annotation class ExcludeFromJSON
```

**Usage in data class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
class User (

        var username: String = "",
        var email: String = "",

        @ExcludeFromJSON
        private var password: String
) {}
```

I expect the annotation to show up in the javaClass reflection and in the compiled java code. It does neither.

**Compiled password var** (no annotation...):

```java
private final var password: kotlin.String /* compiled code */`
```

Comment: What about using `@field:ExcludeFromJSON`?

Comment: @Slaw It works! You've saved my sanity, please post it as an answer too! Then I can give it the good 'ol checkmark. Please also explain why this is a thing (it worked just fine 3 days ago) for future reference (and my interest).

Comment: Has anything updated in your environment within the last few days?

Comment: No, not that I can specifically point out. Same machine, same code, same gradle file. I've also gone back in my git history, that didn't do anything either. So, no, not that I can say of.

Comment: Then I'm not sure why your code used to work. That said, I added an answer to address the problem in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should qualify the annotation with the appropriate use-site target:

```
@field:ExcludeFromJSON
private var password: String
```

This will cause the annotation to be present on the Java field generated by this property.

---

From the *Kotlin Reference* regarding [Annotation Use-site Targets](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets):

> When you're annotating a property or a primary constructor parameter, there are multiple Java elements which are generated from the corresponding Kotlin element, and therefore multiple possible locations for the annotation in the generated Java bytecode. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> The full list of supported use-site targets is:
>
> - `file`;
> - `property` (annotations with this target are not visible to Java);
> - `field`;
> - `get` (property getter);
> - `set` (property setter);
> - `receiver` (receiver parameter of an extension function or property);
> - `param` (constructor parameter);
> - `setparam` (property setter parameter);
> - `delegate` (the field storing the delegate instance for a delegated property).
>
> [...]
>
> If you don't specify a use-site target, the target is chosen according to the `@Target` annotation of the annotation being used. If there are multiple applicable targets, the first applicable target from the following list is used:
>
> - `param`;
> - `property`;
> - `field`.

The three important things to take away from that are:

1. Annotations in Kotlin have a certain amount of ambiguity<sup>1</sup> regarding where they're ultimately applied. For instance, placing your annotation where you did means said annotation could be applied to one of at least *five* different locations: property, field, getter, setter, setter parameter.
2. An annotation applied to a Kotlin property is not visible on the Java side.
3. An annotation on a Kotlin property, without a use-site target, will only be applied to the backing field if it's not also applicable to being applied to the Kotlin property.

Your annotation has both `AnnotationTarget.FIELD` and `AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY` in its `@Target` annotation. Since you don't specify a use-site target, the property takes precedence—meaning the annotation is not visible to Java.

For more information regarding properties and fields, see the [Properties and Fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#properties-and-fields) page of the *Kotlin Reference*.

---

<sup>1. It's not *technically* ambiguous, as everything is well defined.</sup>